# Firebase Emulator showing multiple requests on firestore. Using React Query Firebase

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-query, firebase-tools

I am using `React Query Firebase` and `Firebase Emulator Suite` for an application I am creating for a company that wants to register apprentices and admins. These apprentices can watch induction online and the admins can register apprentices (and others admins), as well as deleting accounts, etc.

Whenever I want to display the apprentice's list on UI, I use React Query Firebase and query the apprentice's collection, using the following code:

```
const {data, isLoading} = useFirestoreQuery(
  ["apprentices"],
  apprenticesCollectionRef,
  {subscribe: true},
  {
    refetchOnMount: false,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    refetchOnReconnect: false,
  }
);
```

This is fine because I can see it only reads one request in the Firestore Requests Tab.

The problem is that when I register a new apprentice or a new admin, at the start it shows only one request (because the query above has the subscribe flag, and it automatically subscribes to new changes, making a new request), but after deleting some apprentices from the collection it starts a weird behaviour.

Whenever I delete, or create a new apprentice, it starts to increase the amount of requests on the Request tab, and when I delete, it is because it changed, the query again fetches the new changes but on the Request tab it shows 3,4,5 and even more as I keep deleting and adding again (because I wanted to check this behaviour).

CHECK: When I register a new account, it uses cloud functions and in the function, it creates the auth account and the user's document in the collection (admins or apprentices). At the start is fine, but as I delete the account and add it again, the requests, for one call, increase.

Does anyone have the same behaviour with the `Firebase Emulator` or `React Query Firebase`?

I tried to change the properties about prefetching, but it did not work.